# Unable to remotely login to one domain from another, although there is a trust created between them

Tags: active-directory

I am having two AD server and each having 1 domain(1 dc) in 1 forest. There is a 2-way Forest-wide trust created between the domains, but users of one domain cannot remotely login to another. But when I am creating a share without giving any access control, users of both the domains can access the share confirming that the trust is created.

Can users remotely login from one domain to another domain? If so, how?

I am very new to these concepts, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

"Remotely login"?  You meen with terminal services (RDP)?  They need permission to log in via remote desktop.

What errors are they getting, and where are they getting them?

Comment: Yes it is actually showing "Allow logon through Terminal services" being disabled.

Comment: Yes it was actually showing "Allow logon through Terminal services" being disabled. But I enabled RDP, but still it was unable to login. What I need to know is,

Suppose there are 2 servers Win2k3 & Win2k8, each running AD and each being the root(& only) domain of respective forests. Now there is a 2-way transitive trust created between these two domains. Users from one domain can access resources in another domain. But is it possible for users of AD server in Win2k8 to login to Win2k3 or vice versa using their respective credentials?

Comment: By default only administrators can log in via Terminal Services. So your Win2k3\user either needs admin rights on the Win2k8 server and vice versa, OR Win2k3\user needs to be in the Remote Desktop Users group on Win2k8 server, and vice versa. The second method is most likely the better choice. Now there are two questions: 1. Is it Terminal Server login that you want, or do you want Users from the Win2k3 Domain to be able to login directly to the console on computers in the Win2k8 Domain? 2. If it's Terminal Service logins you need, is it for specific computers, or for all computers?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was of great help. I could login to Win2k8 with the users of Win2k3. I had to allow Terminal services and Remote Desktop in Win2k8 for users of Win2k3 and vice versa. But the users of Win2k8 could not login to Win2k3 because of "The terminal services has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections". Is there is a limit to the number of allowed connections for terminal services? I am looking into it. But my base problem was solved. Users of one domain can login to another domain when there is a trust between the two. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: All Windows servers (and clients for that fact) have Terminal server capability, but if you do not license the "Terminal Server" role / component (Server only) you have what is (or was) called Administrator mode, which allows 2 (1 for clients - always) concurrent remote sessions.  If this answers your question, please mark it as such.